# Identify Linux passwd file

Tags: python, linux, shadow, passwd

I need help in writing a function (python preferably) to identify if a file is /etc/passwd or etc/shadow. So far I have tried using `print(pw.getpwall())` but this reads the file from the os env. I need a library that takes input and can tell if a file is passwd/shadow file or not

Comment: /etc/shadow cannot be read by ordinary users. Perhaps you could check for permissions.  Also in /etc/passwd, the third column (columns separated by `:`) will always be `0` as it signifies the identification for the `root` user. You can use the `readline` and `split` functions to extract characters.

Comment: Thanks Cibin. I have been able to extract the characters asides the salt value. However my question here is "Is there a library that can identify whether a given file is a passwd/shadow file?" If there isn't, is there a work around to achieve this? 

Like  `def is_passw(path)`  should return `true` is the file provided in the path is a passwd/shadow file

Comment: If you're just trying to determine if the file is `passwd` or `shadow`, why not use pattern matching on the filename - like regex?  Or, by searching for an expected pattern in the file content?  Or, even more simply: `result = file_path == '/etc/passwd'`

Comment: @secjedi No, there isn't a library specifically for this afaik. You'd have to extract and check the conditions elaborated in one of the answers.

Comment: Yes I understand. I have been able to implement checks using regex but I dont want that. I want to modify the pwd.py unix python library so it accept my file instead of reading the /etc/passwd  file the os enviroment. https://github.com/enthought/Python-2.7.3/blob/master/Lib/plat-os2emx/pwd.py
Have you got any idea as to how I can get this done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

passwd and shadow file format differs.

You can write a short function or class. First iteration would be:

1. Find **root** user, almost 100% true that root is the first entry
2. Check 2nd, 6th and 7th column (separator is **:** sign)
3. If 2nd is **x** and 6th is **/root** and 7th is **/bin/*sh** then it is a password file almost in 100%
4. If 2nd is a salt and hash (format: **$salt$hash**) and 6th is a number and 7th is empy then it is a shadow file almost in 100%

Naturally there could be problems:

- Linux is configured not to use shadow file. In this case pasword file 2nd column contains the password
- Linux is configured not to use salt (I guess is it possible or not)

Please check manuals: `man 5 passwd` and `man 5 shadow`

EDIT, 2020-04-24:
Here is the my corrected pwd.py:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os
import sys

passwd_file=('./passwd')

# path conversion handlers
def __nullpathconv(path):
    return path

def __unixpathconv(path):
    return path

# decide what field separator we can try to use - Unix standard, with
# the platform's path separator as an option.  No special field conversion
# handler is required when using the platform's path separator as field
# separator, but are required for the home directory and shell fields when
# using the standard Unix (":") field separator.
__field_sep = {':': __unixpathconv}
if os.pathsep:
    if os.pathsep != ':':
        __field_sep[os.pathsep] = __nullpathconv

# helper routine to identify which separator character is in use
def __get_field_sep(record):
    fs = None
    for c in list(__field_sep.keys()):
        # there should be 6 delimiter characters (for 7 fields)
        if record.count(c) == 6:
            fs = c
            break
    if fs:
        return fs
    else:
        raise KeyError

# class to match the new record field name accessors.
# the resulting object is intended to behave like a read-only tuple,
# with each member also accessible by a field name.
class Passwd:
    def __init__(self, name, passwd, uid, gid, gecos, dir, shell):
        self.__dict__['pw_name'] = name
        self.__dict__['pw_passwd'] = passwd
        self.__dict__['pw_uid'] = uid
        self.__dict__['pw_gid'] = gid
        self.__dict__['pw_gecos'] = gecos
        self.__dict__['pw_dir'] = dir
        self.__dict__['pw_shell'] = shell
        self.__dict__['_record'] = (self.pw_name, self.pw_passwd,
                                    self.pw_uid, self.pw_gid,
                                    self.pw_gecos, self.pw_dir,
                                    self.pw_shell)

    def __len__(self):
        return 7

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self._record[key]

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        raise AttributeError('attribute read-only: %s' % name)

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self._record)

    def __cmp__(self, other):
        this = str(self._record)
        if this == other:
            return 0
        elif this < other:
            return -1
        else:
            return 1

# read the whole file, parsing each entry into tuple form
# with dictionaries to speed recall by UID or passwd name
def __read_passwd_file():
    if passwd_file:
        passwd = open(passwd_file, 'r')
    else:
        raise KeyError
    uidx = {}
    namx = {}
    sep = None
    while 1:
        entry = passwd.readline().strip()
        if len(entry) > 6:
            if sep is None:
                sep = __get_field_sep(entry)
            fields = entry.split(sep)
            for i in (2, 3):
                fields[i] = int(fields[i])
            for i in (5, 6):
                fields[i] = __field_sep[sep](fields[i])
            record = Passwd(*fields)
            if fields[2] not in uidx:
                uidx[fields[2]] = record
            if fields[0] not in namx:
                namx[fields[0]] = record
        elif len(entry) > 0:
            pass                         # skip empty or malformed records
        else:
            break
    passwd.close()
    if len(uidx) == 0:
        raise KeyError
    return (uidx, namx)

# return the passwd database entry by UID
def getpwuid(uid):
    u, n = __read_passwd_file()
    return u[uid]

# return the passwd database entry by passwd name
def getpwnam(name):
    u, n = __read_passwd_file()
    return n[name]

# return all the passwd database entries
def getpwall():
    u, n = __read_passwd_file()
    return list(n.values())

# test harness
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(getpwall())
```

Comment: A more consistent way to identify the root user is their UID/GID are both zero (0)

Comment: Yes I understand. I have been able to implement checks using regex but I dont want that. I want to modify the pwd.py unix python library so it accept my file instead of reading the /etc/passwd  file the os enviroment as  the library  does here: https://github.com/enthought/Python-2.7.3/blob/master/Lib/plat-os2emx/pwd.py
Have you got any idea as to how I can get this done?

Comment: I  guess you want ot use it in python3 environment. First of all You must convert to python3 code. See: [https://docs.python.org/2/library/2to3.html](https://docs.python.org/2/library/2to3.html). After I would delete **try to find passwd file** block (line 62-80) and put passwd filename in command line argument option. In the code the **passwd_file** variable contains the final passwd file. I prefer [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) to process command line arguments.

Comment: I have converted to python3, removed the other lines and instantiated the `passwd_file = './passwd.txt'` i.e my file, but I get a 'TypeError: replace() argument 1 must be str, not None' error at line at line 93.

Comment: This lib intended to in OS/2 systems. As I know in case of Unix/Linux/Mac there is no alternative separator so **os.altsep** is **None** and the lib doesn't handle this scenario.  That's why you have an TypeError. If you only use this script in unix/linux environment than the quickest solution to put **return path* at the begining of the ** __nullpathconv** and  **__unixpathconv** functions. Yes, I know this is a dirty hack but you can test the lib and if it is met your requirements you can finalize it.

Comment: Now I get no error and nothing is returned when I specified my `path='./passwd.txt' for __unixpathconv(path) and __nullpathconv(path)`. I think the library might need a total overhaul to meet this purpose. However, one can achieve this, its fine to make it available so no one goes through this.